# How create option to enable TouchId

Tags: ios, swift

In my application IOS I added in the ViewController a Switch element to user enable or not the TouchId authentication. But I don't t understand if there is a "isEnableToutchId" property or if I need to create an new property in the  plist of my application.

Could help me in the best solution.

thanks

Comment: Look for `LocalIdentification.framework` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext) `canEvaluatePolicy()` and `evaluatePolicy()`

Comment: import LocalAuthentication        Link the LocalAuthentication.framework with your app. see https://the-nerd.be/2015/10/01/authentication-with-touchid/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context.evaluatePolicy(_:error:)`. Here's an example that also performs the auth if available:

```
import LocalAuthentication

let context = LAContext()
var error: NSError?
let reasonString = "Authentication is required to do this."

// Check whether biometric auth is available
if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
      // Do biometric auth
      context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reasonString) { success, error in
           // Handle (success? failure?)
      }
} else {
    // Do fallback
}
```